# Delete only directories that were created before a certain time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I delete only directories that were created before a certain time, let's say I want to delete all directories which were created before 6 hours of current system time.

Code :
get only directories

```
a = next(os.walk('.'))[1]
```

sort by time:

```
a.sort(key=lambda s: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(".", s)))
```

but i want to get list of directories that were created only before a certain time let's say 6 hours before current system time.

Comment: You should be using Python 3, Python 2 is no longer supported. Also what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: @C.Lewis i updated question for what i tried